# Octave: How do I examine variables created in a seperate .m file?

Tags: debugging, octave

I have 2 .m files, for an example say "project_main.m" and "my_function.m"

When I run the program in Octave it works fine. However the only variables I can see in the workspace area are those created in project_main.m, I would like to examine variables created in my_function.m from the workspace area.

Example:

project_main.m:

```
close all;
clear all;
clc;

X = 1;
Y = 2;

%---call function in external .m file---
my_function(X, Y);
```

my_function.m:

```
function functionResults = my_function(iX, iY)

fprintf("X = %d, Y = %d\n", iX, iY);
Z = iX*iY;
fprintf("Z = %d\n", Z);

end
```

This will give me on the command window:

```
X = 1, Y = 2
Z = 2
>>
```

As expected. However in the workspace area I only see `X` and `Y`, not `Z`:
I know I can see `Z` on the command window, but how do I examine variables created in separate .m files from the workspace area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a debugger. [This documentation page](https://octave.org/doc/v4.0.0/Debugging.html) seems like a good start. Either run your function line-by-line using the command window, or set [breakpoints](https://octave.org/doc/v4.0.0/Breakpoints.html#Breakpoints) to return the current function workspace to the global one.

Basically: variables within functions are private to that function and only the ones you output are copied into your workspace. In your case that is nothing, since `fprintf` doesn't return the output, it merely prints to the command window.

Comment: Hi Adriaan, 

That's sorted it, thanks very much for the prompt answer! 

For anyone else as stumped as me in future, using dbstop ("my_function", 1) after the clear all in project_main.m, allowed me to step through the function until Z popped up in the workspace area.